# How To Use Htacess for www.example.com/type.php?user=name

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect `www.example.com/type/name` to `www.example.com/type.php?user=name`

```
{
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/type$ type.php?key=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/type/$ type.php?key=$1
}
```

Please help me about this.

Comment: Why do you `{` and `}` here? Is this Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in your web document root folder (often `public_html` or `htdocs`):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^type/([^/]+)/? type.php?key=$1 [L]
```

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for `.htaccess` files. If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is even installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();` By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for `.htaccess` files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf` and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Answer (score 0):

**try this , hope it helps :**

```
RewriteBase /www.example.com
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^type/(.*)/$ /type.php?user=$1
#OR
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ /$1.php?user=$2
```

**PS :** The first one works only for the url : *www.example.com/type/value* ,the second one works for any page in your site ex: *www.example.com/anypage/value*